# Properly use one twitter bootstrap modal form to add and update information

Tags: php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am creating a content management system using bootstrap, jQuery, php, mySQL.

I am wondering how I can make something work better.

Right now, I have an invoice page with buttons to 'Add Service...', 
Add Accessory...', 'Add Payment...', and so on.

When the user clicks on the buttons to add anything, a bootstrap modal form shows.  Ajax is used with jQuery to process the insert and then the invoice table refreshes showing the new invoice information.

If the user clicks on an item in the invoice table, I have the same bootrap modal form appear with the fields filled in the form to view.  The "Save" button now says "Update."  If info is changed the record is automatically updated in my database and the invoice table refreshes.

How I'm doing this:

The invoice table has a script that sees if the item is clicked.  If so, it updates the 'Save' button to say 'Update'.   Then when the 'Update' button is clicked, the invoice page has jQuery that runs the update script and then changes the button back to say 'Save' and resets the form.

All the item data is stored in 'data-whatever' attributes hidden on the invoice form.  So when the update modal form loads, the 'data-whatever' fields are sent one-by-one to the modal form's inputs.  I have it coded to send the fields to the appropriate field inputs.

It doesn't seem right to me.

Here's a modal which is included on the invoice.php page:

```
<!-- /.modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="modal_form_invoice_payment" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true"></button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">Add/Update/View Payment...</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
             <!-- BEGIN FORM-->
                <form name="payment_form" id="payment_form" data-invid="<?php echo $invoice_id; ?>" method="POST" class="horizontal-form">
                    <div class="form-body">

                        <div class="alert alert-danger display-hide">
                            <button class="close" data-close="alert"></button>
                            You have some form errors. Please check below.
                        </div>
                        <div class="alert alert-success display-hide">
                            <button class="close" data-close="alert"></button>
                            Your form validation is successful!
                        </div>

                    <div class="row">

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="control-label">Type</label>
                                    <select id="types_payments_id" name="types_payments_id" class="form-control">
                                    <option value="">Select One...</option>
                        <?php 
                    if($company->find_types_payments()) { 
                    $types_payments = $company->types_payments(); 
                    foreach ($types_payments as $types_payment_option) { 
                        echo '<option value="' .  $types_payment_option->id . '">' .  $types_payment_option->category . '</option>';
                         };
                    };
                ?>
                                 </select>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-md-6">

                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="control-label">Entered Date</label>
                                        <div class="input-icon right">
                                        <i class="fa"></i>
                                            <input type="text" id="entered_date" name="entered_date" class="datepicker form-control" value="">
                                        </div>
                            </div>
                        </div> 

                    </div>
                        <!--/row-->

                    <div class="row">      
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="control-label">Amount Paid</label>
                                        <div class="input-icon right">
                                        <i class="fa"></i>
                                            <input type="text" id="amount_paid" name="amount_paid" class="currency_mask form-control" value="">
                                        </div>
                            </div>

                        </div>

                        <div class="col-md-6">

                            <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="control-label">Note</label>
                                        <div class="input-icon right">
                                        <i class="fa"></i>
                                            <input type="text" id="note" name="note" class="form-control" value="">
                                        </div>
                            </div>

                        </div>

                    </div>
                        <!--/row-->



                    </div>
                    <input type="hidden" id="inv_payments_id" value="">
                    <input type="hidden" id="invoice_id" name="invoice_id" value="<?php echo $invoice_id; ?>">
                    <input type="hidden" id="contact_id" name="contact_id" value="<?php echo $contact->data()->id; ?>">
                    <input type="hidden" id="company_id" name="company_id" value="<?php echo $company->data()->id; ?>">
                    <div class="modal-footer form-actions right">
                        <button id="cancelPayment" type="button" class="btn default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                        <button id="submitPayment" type="submit" class="btn blue">Save</button>
                    </div>

                </form>
                <!-- END FORM-->
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /.modal-content -->
</div>
<!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div>
<!-- /.modal -->
```

Here's some code from my invoice.php page:

```
if($invoice->find_items_refunds()) { 

$db = $invoice->items_refunds();

 foreach($db AS $result) {

     echo '<tr>
            <td class="refund" data-inv_refunds_id="' . $result->id .'">
                 Refund
                 <br/><br/>
                 <div class="items_buttons" style="display:none">
                 <button type="button" data-deleteID="' . $result->id . '" data-table="invoice_refunds" class="edit_refund edit_button btn btn-xs default">
                 <i class="fa fa-pencil"></i>
                 </button>

                 <button type="button" data-deleteID="' . $result->id . '" data-table="invoice_refunds" class="delete_button btn btn-xs default">
                 <i class="icon-trash"></i>
                 </button>
                 </div>
            </td>
            <td>' . $result->description . '</td>
            <td id="refund_entered_date">' . $result->entered_date . '</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>

            </td>
            <td id="refund_amount_refunded">
                 $' . $result->amount_refunded . '
            </td>
            <td></td>
            <td id="types_payments_id" style="display:none">' . $result->types_payments_id . '</td>
            <td id="refund_note" style="display:none">' . $result->refund_note . '</td>
        </tr>';
 }
```

}

This is a sample from the invoice that shows 'payments.'  I am hiding information in the payments rows like it's id for instance.  Then when that row is clicked on the invoice page I have separate jQuery that opens the same form I use to 'save' new payment info, but this time it populates the form with the data (hidden and visible) from the payment row.

Is there a better way?  If I have a table record that has a lot of data in it, I don't think I'd want to hide all of that info in the row.

I'm thinking what I need to do is find a way that when the modal form opens, and if I'm updating a record then query the database for ALL the information to fill the fields in the form.

I hope I explained that right.

Or do should I just make an "Add form" and a separate "Update form"?  I thought it would be better practice to have one form and use it to add new data and update it whenever it's shown.

Here's the javascript that handles the form:

```
//when cancel is selected while on bootsrap modal forms, reset whole form. must do for each modal
$("#modal_form_invoice_payment #cancelPayment").click(function() {
    //reset form, hide it, and reload table and totals
    $('#modal_form_invoice_payment').find('form')[0].reset();
    //remove checkmark from any field that was validation successfully and remove green outline from has-success validation
    $('#modal_form_invoice_payment .fa').removeClass('fa-check');
    $('#modal_form_invoice_payment .form-group').removeClass('has-success');
    $('#modal_form_invoice_payment .form-group').removeClass('has-error');
    $('#modal_form_invoice_payment .fa').removeClass('fa-warning');
    $('#modal_form_invoice_payment .alert').hide();
    $('#modal_form_invoice_payment #submitPayment').html('Save');
});

$('.edit_payment').click(function() {

    //once edit_payment is clicked, disable all edit feature and restore invoice table back to normal.

    $('#invoice_block .edit_me').editable('toggleDisabled');
           //show/hide buttons for items
           if($('.items_buttons').is(":visible")) {
              $('.items_buttons').hide();
           } else {
              $('.items_buttons').show(); 
           }
            if($("#print").is(":visible")) {
              $('#print').hide();
           } else {
              $('#print').show(); 
           }
        //enable/disable add and delete buttons accordingly.      
        if($('#add_button').is(":disabled")) {
              $('#add_button').attr("disabled",false);
           } else {
              $('#add_button').attr("disabled",true);
           }

        if($('#delete_button').is(":disabled")) {
              $('#delete_button').attr("disabled",false);
           } else {
              $('#delete_button').attr("disabled",true);
           }   

//make the text value of id's parsed into integers so the dropdown can be populated with that value. has to be changed to int fist, else doesn't populate.
//also trim description - remove white spaces from how this table is formatted.
var $payments_id = $(this).closest("tr").find(".payment").attr("data-inv_payments_id");
var $types_payments_id = parseInt($(this).closest("tr").find("#types_payments_id").text() , 10);
var $payment_note = $.trim($(this).closest("tr").find("#payment_note").text());
var $payment_amount_paid = $(this).closest("tr").find("#payment_amount_paid").text();
var $payment_entered_date = $(this).closest("tr").find("#payment_entered_date").text();  

    //set update form values and changed text from Save to Update
    $('#modal_form_invoice_payment #inv_payments_id').val($payments_id);
    $('#modal_form_invoice_payment #types_payments_id').val($types_payments_id);
    $('#modal_form_invoice_payment #note').val($payment_note);
    $('#modal_form_invoice_payment #amount_paid').val($payment_amount_paid);
    $('#modal_form_invoice_payment #entered_date').val($payment_entered_date);
    $('#modal_form_invoice_payment #submitPayment').html('Update');
    $('#modal_form_invoice_payment').modal('show');

});
```

Here's the jQuery that handles the form validation:

```
    //VALIDATE PAYMENT FORM
var form_payment = $('#payment_form');
var inv_id_payment = $('#payment_form').attr("data-invid");
var error_payment = $('.alert-danger', form_payment);
var success_payment = $('.alert-success', form_payment);

var validateAdjustment = $('#payment_form').validate({
    errorElement: 'span', //default input error message container
    errorClass: 'help-block help-block-error', // default input error message class
    focusInvalid: true, // do not focus the last invalid input
    ignore: "",  // validate all fields including form hidden input
    rules: {
        entered_date: {
            required: true
        },
        amount_paid: {
            required: true
        },
        types_payments_id: {
            required: true
        }
    },

    invalidHandler: function (event, validator) { //display error alert on form submit              
               success_payment.hide();
               error_payment.show();
               App.scrollTo(error_payment, -200);
    },

    errorPlacement: function (error, element) { // render error placement for each input type
                var icon = $(element).parent('.input-icon').children('i');
                icon.removeClass('fa-check').addClass("fa-warning");  
                icon.attr("data-original-title", error.text()).tooltip();
    },


    highlight: function (element) { // hightlight error inputs
                $(element)
                    .closest('.form-group').removeClass("has-success").addClass('has-error'); // set error class to the control group   
    },

    unhighlight: function (element) { // revert the change done by highlight

    },

    success: function (label, element) {
        var icon = $(element).parent('.input-icon').children('i');
        $(element).closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-error').addClass('has-success'); // set success class to the control group
        icon.removeClass("fa-warning").addClass("fa-check");
    },

    submitHandler: function(form_payment) {

        //remove blank inputs so they aren't passed into the db and are inserted as NULL
        var data = $("#payment_form").serialize();

        if($('#payment_form #submitPayment').text() == 'Save') { 
            //save
                    $.ajax({
                    url: "ajax_insert.php?table=invoice_payments",
                    type: form_payment.method,
                    dataType: 'json',
                    data: data,
                    success: function(response) {
                            //response here if data response
                        if (response) {

                            if(response.success) {
                                //reset form, hide it, and reload table and totals
                            $('#modal_form_invoice_payment').find('form')[0].reset();
                            error_payment.hide(); //if it's visible, hide it.
                            //remove checkmark from any field that was validation successfully and remove green outline from has-success validation
                            $('#modal_form_invoice_payment .fa').removeClass('fa-check');
                            $('#modal_form_invoice_payment .form-group').removeClass('has-success');
                            $('#modal_form_invoice_payment').modal('hide');
                            $('#invoice_table').load('content_invoice_table.php', { "inv_id": inv_id_payment});
                            $('#invoice_totals').load('content_invoice_totals.php', { "inv_id": inv_id_payment});
                            toastr.info('Payment entry recorded!');
                            } else { 
                             toastr.error('Error!');
                            }
                                }
                    }            
                });    


        } else {
            //get update id value from hidden field
            var inv_payments_id = $('#payment_form #inv_payments_id').val();

            //update
             $.ajax({
                    url: 'ajax_update.php?table=invoice_payments&id='+inv_payments_id,
                    type: form_payment.method,
                    dataType: 'json',
                    data: data,
                    success: function(response) {
                            //response here if data response
                        if (response) {

                            if(response.success) {
                                //reset form, hide it, and reload table and totals
                            $('#modal_form_invoice_payment').find('form')[0].reset();
                            error_payment.hide(); //if it's visible, hide it.
                            //remove checkmark from any field that was validation successfully and remove green outline from has-success validation
                            $('#modal_form_invoice_payment .fa').removeClass('fa-check');
                            $('#modal_form_invoice_payment .form-group').removeClass('has-success');
                            //restore form to Save mode
                            $('#modal_form_invoice_payment #submitPayment').html('Save');
                            $('#modal_form_invoice_payment').modal('hide');
                            $('#invoice_table').load('content_invoice_table.php', { "inv_id": inv_id_payment});
                            $('#invoice_totals').load('content_invoice_totals.php', { "inv_id": inv_id_payment});
                            toastr.info('Payment entry updated!');
                            } else { 
                             toastr.error('Error!');
                            }
                                }
                    }            
                });    


        };             

    }

 });
```

Comment: where is your javascript code?

Comment: I updated the question with the javascript. Thanks.

Comment: I would go with this route ... http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-related-target ... using `$('#exampleModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {` event will help streamline your code

Comment: Should I go about it like this?

    $('#modal_form_insurance_claim').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {
          
       if 'UPDATE MODE' then get the data needed from database, fill the form fields, change button form "SAVE" to "UPDATE"


    });